# Getting exact angle a line passing through two dots will make with X Axis

Tags: python, math, geometry, trigonometry

I'm getting wrong output with atan2 function.

I have 2 variable points i.e. p1=(x1,y1)  p2=(x2,y2)

```
angleFun(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dx=x2-x1
    dy=y2-y1
    radAngle = math.atan2(dy, dx)
    degAngle = math.degrees(radAngle)
    if degAngle<0:
       degAngle+=360
    print (angle)
```

now this code works fine for 0 and 90 degree line only, for other values it doesnt give accurate value.

for ex:

[image]

([0.49609900927256284, 0.5], [0.5039009907274372, 0.5])
gives 00 angle.

[image]

([0.5, 0.506935094626555], [0.5, 0.49306490537344505])
gives 270 degrees

but

[image]

([0.4972415830032833, 0.5049038524386074], [0.5027584169967166, 0.4950961475613926])
gives 299.357753543 degrees.

whereas it should give 315 or -45 degrees.

Really not able to understand, why is that. any angle other than 0 and 90 gets the wrong value. Strictly python and math library. Struggling with this for quiet a time now. any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's `match.atan2`?  Just a typo?

Comment: Better copy and paste your code directly into the question.

Comment: For the purposes of the question, how about using example inputs that are easier for us to evaluate by eye?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ([0.4972415830032833, 0.5049038524386074], [0.5027584169967166, 0.4950961475613926]) gives 299.357753543 degrees.

> whereas it should give 315 or -45 degrees.

No, it shouldn't.  In that case,

```
dx == 0.5027584169967166 - 0.4972415830032833 == 0.005516833993433334
dy == 0.4950961475613926 - 0.5049038524386074 == -0.009807704877214773
```

For +315 / -45 degrees, you need `dx > 0` and `dy == -dx`.  The latter condition is not satisfied by the specified input.  Qualitatively, you would expect a result farther from angle 0, exactly as you observe. With `dy` approximately equal to `-2 * dx`, something near +300 / -60 is the right ballpark.  I see no reason to think that your code is computing an incorrect answer for that input.